# regex to allow one decimal number or a range of decimal number

Tags: regex

I need a JavaScript regular expression which matches a single decimal number *or* a range of decimal number:

`8,4-10      true
8,4-10,5    true
8,4-10,5-3  false
8,4-        false
25          true
25,5        true
24.1        false
1a          false
abc         false`

I have come up with this pattern, but it doesn't give correct result:

`(([0-9])+(,([0-9])+)?)?(-(([0-9])+(,([0-9])+)?))?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is correct, you just need to anchor it to make sure you're matching the whole string, not just part of it.

Simplifying what can be, it becomes:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:,\d+)?)?$
```

`\d` is short for `[0-9]`, `(?:...)` is a non capturing group, `^$` are anchors matching the beginning and end of the string (making sure there is nothing other than what you want).

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/jG5eS2).