# Validating user input of decimal number

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I have a wpf text box and I want to check as the user inputs into it that they are only using 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . [Decimal Point] characters for decimal numbers. I use this textbox to convert to a decimal later

I am using the follow articles as a starting point 
[Regex Match](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) [Preview Text Input example](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/previewtextinput/) [regex-to-allow-one-decimal-number-or-a-range-of-decimal-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388776/regex-to-allow-one-decimal-number-or-a-range-of-decimal-number)

Here is my xaml

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="tbTaxFreeLimit" Width="90" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                             AcceptsTab="True" 
                                             PreviewTextInput="tbDecimalCheck_PreviewTextInput"
                                            />
```

And c#

```
private void tbDecimalCheck_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
     // Test for decimal
     if (IsNumeric(e.Text)==false)
         e.Handled = true;
}

private bool IsNumeric(string s)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(@"^[0-9]");

    return r.IsMatch(s);
}
```

This example works fine for 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 but I can not enter the decimal point .

If I change the to following code below it has no effect

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^[0-9].");
```

Comment: How about using `decimal.Parse` instead of regex with a proper culture settings? Regex is not the best way on such a case.

Comment: instead of regex try to actually convert input value into `decimal`. If that fails - show red border.

Comment: @SonerGönül better yet `decimal.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^\d+\.?\d*$");
```

Explanation: "^" matches the beginning of the string; \d+ matches one or more digits, \.? matches an optional decimal point, and \d* matches zero or more digits. "$" matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 5):

Your regex `^[0-9].` is saying from the start of the string match one character in the range `0-9` and then match any character (`.` means any character). That's not what you want. You'd need to match any number of characters, an optional decimal point, and then a bunch more numbers. Something like:

```
^\d+\.?\d*$
```

Which says 1 or more (`+`) digit (`\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`), 0 or 1 (`?`) decimal point (the `.` has to be escaped to match a literal `.` hence `\.`) and then 0 or more (`*`) digits.

This fixes your regex, but doing this on a text input is kind of a pain and you are better off letting the user enter text and then validating it with something like `decimal.TryParse` rather than trying to restrict while they type. Why? Consider the user enters:

```
1     // this is valid
```

And then:

```
1.    // this is still valid
```

And then:

```
1.2   // still valid
```

And then they realize they meant `2.2`, so what do they do? They delete the `1` to give:

```
.2     // Buzzzz, not valid
```

That's really annoying for a user. The user tries to delete the `1` and the control stubbornly keeps rejecting the change. Why? The user doesn't know. Don't turn entering user input into a game of "guess what the rules are".

Another thing to consider, which may or may not be a problem for you, is that not all cultures use `.` as a decimal separator. In fact [most of the world doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg).

So don't cancel text entry, use `TryParse` (with appropriate cultural settings) and just set an error on the `TextBox` rather than stop user entering text. Just don't let the user go to whatever the next stage is until they resolve the problem with the numeric entry.

Comment: Thanks for  a great answer and explanation. My purpose was to ensure control of the input, but I can see how it would really frustrate the user. I use an TryParse method to do a final verification, so I need to just expand on it abit. By error do you mean something like turn an cross icon visible next to the text box with a tooltip of the reason for the error?

Comment: @IanW: Yes. A red border around a control is a very common element to indicate errors. A tooltip is also useful if it's not obvious to the user what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the tips much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression may not be the most readable/maintainable way to do this.

Try parsing it;

```
private bool IsNumeric(string s) => decimal.TryParse(s, out var value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtTransactionAmount.Text, @"[^0-9].[^0-9]")
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some explanation as though why this answer the question